# iconTint in the Toolbar menu in Android

Tags: android, menu, material-design, android-toolbar

I have a menu:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/search"
            android:iconTint="@color/iconBackground"
            app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_info_bar"
            android:icon="@drawable/search_barcod"
            android:iconTint="@color/iconBackground"
            app:showAsAction="always" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_filter_list"
            android:icon="@drawable/select_auction"
            android:iconTint="@color/iconBackground"
            app:showAsAction="always" />

    </menu>
```

which is added to the `ToolBar`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main_top"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/logo"
        app:navigationIconTint="@color/iconBackground"
        app:title="@string/app_name" />
```

The colors of **iconBackground** are set differently for **light** and **dark** themes.

for a **light** theme

```
<color name="iconBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
```

for a **dark** theme

```
<color name="iconBackground">#292929</color>
```

But for some reason, the color of the icons in the menu on the `Toolbar` is always white, while **navigationIcon** changes its color.
What could be the reason?

At the same time, the **xml** menu is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one offered anything, it made it easier. Translated all the icons into **Vector set (xml)** vector format and assigned the color of the **icon Background** in the **XML** file itself